# $\mathbb{Z}[X]/ \langle 2X-1\rangle$ and finite algebra, integral and fibres

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra

Edit: I don't understand why there are 2 downvotes on this problem.

Consider the following problem:

Problem: Let $A=\mathbb{Z}[X]/\langle 2X-1\rangle$ be the residue class $\mathbb{Z}$-algebra of the polynomial algebra $\mathbb{Z}[X]$ by the ideal generated by $2X-1$ and let $\phi \colon \mathbb{Z}\hookrightarrow \mathbb{Z}[X]\to A$ be the canonical ring homomorphism.

(a) Is $A$ a finite algebra over $\mathbb{Z}$? Is $A$ integral over $\mathbb{Z}$?

(b) Describe the fibres of the map $\operatorname{Spec} \phi \colon \operatorname{Spec} A \to \operatorname{Spec} \mathbb{Z}$.

My thoughts:

(a) Let $A$ be a finite algebra over $\mathbb{Z}$. Then $\mathbb{Z}[X]/\langle 2X-1\rangle= \mathbb{Z} a_1 + \dots + \mathbb{Z} a_n$. All  $a_i$'s $\in A$.  But I am not able to get any contradiction by this because I am not sure what theorem should I use now, and obviously this method will not work if $A$ is actually a finite algebra over $\mathbb{Z}$.

Let $a\in \mathbb{Z}[X]/ \langle 2X-1\rangle$. Then $a= z X + \langle 2X-1\rangle$ and  $z\in \mathbb{Z}$. If $a$ is integral over  $\mathbb{Z}$ then $a^n+ z_{n-1} a^{n-1} +\dots +a_0=0$. But I am not sure how exactly to prove or contradict this and need help.

(b) This map $\phi$ is given by $\{x\in \operatorname{Spec} A \mid f (\operatorname{Spec} A) = \operatorname{Spec} \mathbb{Z}\}$. The prime ideals of $\mathbb{Z}$ are $(0)$ and $p \mathbb{Z}$. But I am not able to find prime ideals of $\mathbb{Z}[X]/\langle 2X-1\rangle$. Can you please help me with this?

Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps it will help you to have a less abstract view of your ring. It’s just $\Bbb Z[\frac12]$, or even more concretely, the ring of rational numbers with only powers of $2$ in the denominator.

Comment: What is a “finite algebra”?

Comment: @Lubin Ya, I was able to deduce that but was not able to proceed from here.

Comment: @MarkSaving A is called finite B algebra if there exists finitely many elements $a_1,...,a_n \in A $ such $A=B a_1 +...+ Ba_n$.

Comment: In the statement of your problem, do you want $A = \mathbb{Z}[X]/\left<2X-1\right>$?

Comment: @ReginaldAnderson I am not able to understand what you are trying to say.

Comment: In the title of your question, you have $\mathbb{Z}[X]/\left<2X-1\right>$ and in the statement of your problem you have $\mathbb{Z}/\left<2X-1\right>$

Comment: @ReginaldAnderson You are right. Thank you very much for pointing.

Comment: @ReginaldAnderson Kindly have a look at the edit.

Answer (score 2):

For part (a):

Recall the following Lemma:

> Let $M$ be an $R$-module. Then $M$ is a finitely generated $R$-module if and only if any set $S \subseteq M$ which generates $M$ has a finite subset which also generates $M$.

An interesting aside: this is actually true for any type of algebraic structure (you could replace $R$-module with group, ring, etc. and the Lemma would still hold).

Now let’s consider the module at hand, $M = \mathbb{Z}[X] / (2X - 1)$. A generating set for this module is $S = \{X^n \mid n \in \mathbb{N}\}$, and it’s easy to show that no finite subset of $S$ can generate $M$ (it’s a good exercise for the reader). Therefore, $M$ is not finitely generated as a $\mathbb{Z}$-module. $\square$

For part (b):

It turns out that $A$ is a principal ideal domain. To prove this, note that $\mathbb{Z}$ is a PID, hence Noetherian. Then by Hilbert’s basis theorem, $\mathbb{Z}[X]$ is also Noetherian. Any quotient of a Noetherian ring is Noetherian, so $A$ is Noetherian. Then any ideal $I$ of $A$ is finitely generated. Then in particular, we can show that $I$ is generated by some sequence $m_1 X^n, m_2 X^n, \ldots, m_k X^n$ (exercise). Then use the fact that $\mathbb{Z}$ is a PID to find some $m$ such that $I = (m X^n)$.

In fact, since $X$ and $2$ are inverses, ideals of $A$ can all be written as $(n)$ for some $n$ either zero or odd. It’s not too hard to show that for zero or odd integers $n, m$, we have $(n) = (m)$ iff $n = \pm m$. From here, we see that the prime ideals of $A$ are $(0)$ and $(p)$ for odd prime $p$, which tells us that the fibre $f^{-1}(I)$ is empty if $I = (2)$ and a singleton otherwise.

Comment: The lemma you wrote in (a) was not part of my algebra courses. Can you please give a proof of it or add a link of proof of it?

Comment: @YOja Suppose every set $S$ generation $M$ has a finite generating subset. Then $S = M$ generates $M$ and thus has a finite generating subset. Conversely, suppose $M$ is generated by $\{m_1, \ldots, m_n\}$ and also by $S$. Let $M’ = \{x \in M \mid $ there is finite $S’ \subseteq S$ such that $x$ is in the submodule generated by $S’\}$. Show $M’ = M$ by showing $M’$ is a submodule containing $S$. Pick finite $S_1, \ldots, S_n \subseteq S$ such that for all $i$, $x_i$ is in the submodule generated by $S_i$. Then $S_1 \cup \cdots \cup S_n \subseteq S$ is finite and generates $M$.

Comment: In (a) you forgot to tell me about whether A is integral over $\mathbb{Z}$ or not? Can you please help me with that?

Comment: How does in (b) X and 2 being inverses of each other implies that  Ideals of A can be written as (n) for some n?

Comment: @Avenger (a) It’s straightforward to show directly that $X$ is not an integral element over $\mathbb{Z}$. (b) We see that we can write $I = (m X^n)$. Since $X$ is invertible, this means $I = (m)$. If $m$ is nonzero, we can write $m = n 2^k$ for some odd $n$; then $(n 2^k) = (n)$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment. Can you please tell how can you write I=(m) if X is given invertible and $(n 2^k)=(n)?